# can't hide bottom bar in view controller after pushing segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

in just one view controller appears this bottom bar after pushing the VC with my segue.

[image: bottombar]

i can't get it hided. i don't want that this bottom bar appears. what kind of bar is this? how do i get it away?

i have a uiTextField in this VC, is this calling that bar? i don't need the keyboard or this bar.

i tried to disable it in my storyboard, but i always appears in this vc.

EDIT: My TextField:
.h

```
@interface GameOverViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
```

}

.m

```
@implementation UITextField (DisableCopyPaste)

-(BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender
{

return NO;
return [super canPerformAction:action withSender:sender];
}

@end

@implementation GameOverViewController

NSString *text1;



text1 = @"";

UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_nameField.inputView = testView;
[_nameField becomeFirstResponder];
_nameField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[[UITextField appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]]; //set Color of Cursor
```

Buttons for TextField:

```
if (_nameField.text.length <=11) {

    if (_nameField.isEditing) {
        text1 = [text1 stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];
        [_nameField setText:text1];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a UIToolbar. Select your view controller in storyboard, under the 'Utilities' select the 'Attributes inspector' tab and set 'Bottom bar' to none.

If you are using UINavigationController, you can do the same for the navigation controller (unchecking 'shows Toolbar' under same tab will also help) or programmatically you can write this in your view controller

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

Comment: ok, i tried now to disable my textfield and it was gone! my textfield is showing this bar. how can i get rid of this bar?

Comment: That's unusual, I don't think a textfield would show a bottom bar anywhere itself. Are you using a custom UITextField ?

Comment: no, just a textfield with "custom keys". there is no keyboard needed in my app. just like: if (_nameField.isEditing) {
            text1 = [text1 stringByAppendingString:[sender currentTitle]];
            [_nameField setText:text1];
        }

Comment: If you don't need a keyboard in your app, what are you using UITextField for? It is used to obtain the user input

Comment: live updated my question again, so that you can see, how Im using it

Comment: i know, but i can't understand where this bar comes from... i just want to know why and how :)

Comment: UIView* testView = [[UIView alloc] init];
_nameField.inputView = testView; -- this code hides the keyboard but doesn't tell me what else is presented on screen